# Reverse UI-scrolling in Unity Ubuntu 16.04 with libinput

Tags: unity, touchpad, scrolling, libinput

How can I reverse the UI-scrolling in Unity? My trackpad recognizes 2 fingers for scroll, but whenever I drag upwards, it scrolls up. I want it to be reverse, as if the trackpad mimics a touch-screen when scrolling.

(When I drag up, I scroll down).

I had it working in Unity until I tried out Gnome by installing it and testing it out. I have since purged gnome from my system, but the scrolling was inverted back to move up -> scroll up.

Comment: What sort of touchpad is it?

Comment: Built in on a MacBook Pro (MacBook 11.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf` and add

```
Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
```

to the touchpad section of that file before `EndSection`.

It can be done by

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but had to remove it from terminal, because the machine wasn't able to load GUI at boot - but I will give it another try.

Comment: You probably placed it to a wrong part of the file or made a typo there. It works with no problems if you do it right.

Comment: Just performed a successful reboot, and I still have natural scrolling! I think the error I made last time was excluding the 'Option' at the start. The wiki didn't mention it at all. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great, but I don't have a confguration file for libinput. `find / -name '*libinput*.conf'`gives me nothing. `apt list --installed | grep libinput` shows that `libinput-bin` and `libinput10`are installed. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Following this [guide:](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2017/02/23/enable-natural-scrolling-for-trackpads-using-libinput/)

```
xinput --list
```

and found my trackpad, bcm5974. Then checked properties of it:

```
xinput --list-props bcm5974
```

and saw

```
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (350):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (351):       0
```

changed them by:

```
xinput --set-prop bcm5974 "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

And problem is fixed.

Comment: This will work till next reboot. You'd better set it up in the `libinput.conf`

Comment: How would that be done? Where is it located? Last time I tried to edit a .conf file using their Wiki, I ended up not being able to boot with GUI.

Comment: See my answer. I will add a command.

Answer (score 0):

I have an GUI option for this in System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> the touchpad entry tab. Don't you?

Comment: Under Mouse & Touchpad I have:
Primary button [Left, right] and a Double-click speed adjust.

Comment: Then try reversing the speed. In console, type `synclient VertScrollDelta=-1` It is either 1 or -1. Or you can use *larger* number if it gets too fast.

Comment: Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
I have Libinput gestures installed for some easy 3-finger macros. It is a long time since I installed it and configured it, so I can't find the config file or the website I used to create it.

Comment: Wow. Non-synaptics touchpads are outside my experience.

Comment: This is not related to either the touchpad is synaptics. It depends on which user space driver is used. OP is using `libinput`. It does not have a GUI yet.

Answer (score 0):

For most people, the answer is:

1. Search for "system settings"
2. "Mouse & Touchpad"
3. Enable "natural scrolling"